# Specify executable directory for IPOPT in JuMP/Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump, ipopt

I want to specify my IPOPT directory. In Python with Pyomo I can do this in one line:

`solver = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='/my/path/to/ipopt')`

In Julia with JuMP I have:

`ipopt_solver = JuMP.optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "tol"=>1e-6, "print_level"=>0)`

Is there a way to do the same thing? I want Julia to use my specified path to IPOPT rather than the default IPOPT from the package manager.

Comment: Here are the instructions: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/developers/custom_solver_binaries/   However, I do not know how to install Ipopt binaries so I am not able to test the on Ipopt, but with some hacking theses should work with any solver

Comment: Good question... in the doc there is lot of info in building your own version of the solver engine and override the JLL package, but nothing on you already have the binary and want simply use this... try the forum on Discourse or open an issue on github..

Answer (score 0):

Ipopt.jl does not use the executable.

Use `AmplNLWriter.jl` instead: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/packages/AmplNLWriter/

```
using JuMP, AmplNLWriter
model = Model(() -> AmplNLWriter.Optimizer("/my/path/to/ipopt"))
```